# Time stamp in google script (not active sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a script below to fill a sheet "Data" based on input from "Form". There's a button on 'Form' sheet which is linked to the function below. I would like for it to also time stamp , into column D (in the 'Data' sheet) the moment the script is run / submitted.

Most of the time stamp scripts i've seen only update if it is the active sheet that is being updated. Here the updated sheet is not active. Appreciate any help with this.

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet
   
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("K4").getValue(),
                  formSS.getRange("K5").getValue(),]];
   
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues(values);

  //Clear the fields after submit
formSS.getRange("K4").clear();
formSS.getRange("K5").clear();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

You are not using an active sheet in your current script.  You are accessing specific sheets with the `getSheetByName()` method.

I always try to make the minimum number of calls `getValue()/getValues()` and `setValue()/setValues()` so since you are getting contiguous cells I modified your `values` `getValue()` to become a `getValues()`, the same for `clear()`.

You are not specific but I'm assuming you want the time stamp in column D of the row added to Data.  If column C contains data or formula that you don't want disturbed than you can make two calls one `setValues()` containing the array and one `setValue()` containing the date.

Notice in `setValues()` I'm transforming a 1D array into a 2D array by `[values]`.

**Code.gs**

```
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //Data Sheet
   
  //Input Values
  var values = formSS.getRange("K4:K5").getValues(); // in the form [[1],[2]]
  values.flat(); // now of the form [1,2]
  values = values.concat([0,new Date()]);  // now of the form [1,2,0,date]
   
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([values]);  // now of the form [[1.2,0,date]]

  //Clear the fields after submit
  formSS.getRange("K4:K5").clear();
}
```

**Reference**

- [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)